# Show GRUB menu from the start on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, boot, grub2

I'm new on Ubuntu, I just installed the 13.04 version, and I'd like to know if there is any way to make the Grub menu be the first thing to appear in my screen when I tun on my computer.

If there is, could you explain me the steps to follow?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can't because the BIOS is the first software (also called firmware) executed by your computer and GRUB is called from the BIOS. If you don't want to see the BIOS console, use the `quiet boot` option in your BIOS options.
To see the BIOS options press F2, F8, F12 or Canc, depending on your BIOS version and model.
If the BIOS takes too much time you can disable the `virus boot memory protection` (leave it enabled if you use Windows or use the pc for production purposes) and the extra device checks.
Have a nice day.

Comment: Don't forget to press the up arrow on my answer. Do the same on other useful answers & questions. ;-)